# Show text area onclick "Yes" radio button and stay hidden by default or when clicked "No" radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this html code and trying to figure out how I can create text area box using java script when I select only "Yes" radio button. That text area should stay hide by default or when select "NO".

```
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>        
    <td class="data_yy yyy1">
       <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"/><label>Yes</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"/><label>No</label>
   </td>
   <td class="data_xx xxx1"> Are you in high school?</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
function hideShowJacks(val) {
  if (val == "Y") {
    $("#area").show();
  } else {
    $("#area").hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#area {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>        
    <td class="data_yy yyy1">
       <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"/><label>Yes</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"/><label>No</label>
   </td>
   <td class="data_xx xxx1"> Are you in high school?</td>
</tr>
</table>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
```

If you prefer to use Javascript instead of jQuery:

```js
function hideShowJacks(val) {
  if (val == "Y") {
    document.getElementById("area").style.display = "block";
  } else {

    document.getElementById("area").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#area {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>        
    <td class="data_yy yyy1">
       <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"/><label>Yes</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"/><label>No</label>
   </td>
   <td class="data_xx xxx1"> Are you in high school?</td>
</tr>
</table>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Matthias_h, I am new to Javascript. I have a question. I already have some JavaScript codes exist in my html file where I see one of them has:  <script type ="text/javascript" src=../jquery/apTextCounter/jquery.apTextCounter.js"</script>. To follow the same patter, would that be okay to use your Javascript header code using this way: <script type="text/javascript" src=.../ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: @pg_max I'd think that if you already include jquery.apTextCounter.js you also include jQuery as jquery.apTextCounter.js looks like a file that depends on using jQuery. But if you're not including jQuery it would be okay to use the script include like you suggested. Just make sure that you include jQuery before you include any other scripts that depends on jQuery.

Comment: so you suggest I do not need to add <script type="text/javascript" src=.../ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> separately anymore since I already have  <script type ="text/javascript" src=../jquery/apTextCounter/jquery.apTextCounter.js"</script> in the file? and Yes, I will be using jquery.

Comment: @pg_max No, I suggest you check if you already include jQuery because you seem to include a script that - because of its name - seems to depend on jQuery. If you really don't include jQuery, then add the script tag for including jQuery before the script tag of jQuery.apTextCounter.js.

Comment: @Hi Matthias_h- so I already have this: <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.js"></script> in the file. Sorry I was not totally clear what you meant. These are the only scripts I have in my html file: <script type ="text/javascript" src=../jquery/apTextCounter/jquery.apTextCounter.js"</script> and <script type="text/javascript" scr ="../jquery/jquery.js">. Hopefully I made sense.

Comment: @pg_max Yes you did. And so you already include jQuery and don't need to add it another time. Btw, if I should have answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer to resolve your question as answered/solved.

Comment: Thank you@Hi Matthias_h- So I do not need to add this:  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> at all. Thank you again. Awesome. Appreciate your help and yes, I will add this as resolved.

Comment: @pg_max Glad that I was able to help. And in case you don't know how accepting an answer works, check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Answer (score 0):

You can add an text field and toggle the show hide using javascript.
Here is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
</head>
<body>
<table class="table100" width="150%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>        
    <td class="data_yy yyy1">
       <input type="radio" name="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks(event);"/><label>Yes</label> 
        <input type="radio" name="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks(event);"/><label>No</label>
   </td>
   <td class="data_xx xxx1"> Are you in high school?</td>
   <textarea id="test" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
   
  </tr>
</table>

  
  <script>
    const inputBox = document.querySelector('#test');
    inputBox.style.display = 'none';
    
    function hideShowJacks(event) {
      const selectValue = event.target.value;
      if(selectValue === 'Y') {
        inputBox.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        inputBox.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```